# Print all paths of a binary tree (DFS)

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search

I was trying to print all paths(root-to-leaf paths) of binary tree but of no avail.

My strategy is to use the recursion, having the base case as `either tree is None or tree node is leaf return` Otherwise, traverse through left and right of the tree.

But I can't find a way to retain both of left and right tree.

```
def pathSum(self, root, target, result):

    if not root:
        return []

    if not root.left and not root.right:
        return [root.val]

    for i in [root.left, root.right]:
        path = [root.val] + self.pathSum(i, target, result)
        print("path", path)
        return path
```

Comment: Please define a 'path' - is it a tree traversal, or a route from root to a leaf?

Comment: A path is a root to leaf path

Comment: I think this should be pretty similar to pre-order traversal

Answer (score 1):

The idea is building the path (list) at each node visit, if current node is a leaf, add current to path and print it, if no, just add current to extend the path:

```
def pathSum(self, path):

    if not self.left and not self.right:
        print(path + [self.val])
        return

    self.left.pathSum(path + [self.val])
    self.right.pathSum(path + [self.val])


root.pathSum([])
```

Update: If you want to keep all paths:

```
def pathSum(self, current_path, all_paths):

    if not self.left and not self.right:
        print('Path found: ' + str(current_path + [self.val]))
        all_paths.append(current_path + [self.val])
        return

    self.left.pathSum(current_path + [self.val], all_paths)
    self.right.pathSum(current_path + [self.val], all_paths)

all_paths = []

root.pathSum([], all_paths)

print('All paths: ' + str(all_paths))
```

Answer (score -1):

Through some iterations, I found the following solution works. But I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way of finding all leaf-root paths.

The idea behind this solution is pre-order traversal

```
def allPaths(self, root, path, all_path):
    if not root.left and not root.right:
        path.append(root.val)
        all_path.append(path[:])
        return

    if root:
        path.append(root.val)
        self.allPaths(root.left, path, all_path)
        path.pop(-1)
        self.allPaths(root.right, path, all_path)
        path.pop(-1)
    return all_path
```

Comment: I checked again. This solution is still wrong. as ```path.pop(-1)```` removes the very root node once it traverse back to the root of the tree.